# How to block intra package imports

Tags: python, python-3.x, configuration, python-import

I'm building a python application and my codebase has the following structure:

```
/utils
  /foo
/package_1
  /foo
/package_2
  /foo
/whatever
```

I would like to enforce the following rules:

1. In **utils** package is possible to import only from **utils** package itself
2. In **package_1** is possible to import from **utils** and **package_1** itself
3. In **package_2** is possible to import from **utils** and **package_2** itself
4. In **whatever** you can import from all the other packages

Which automatic strategy can I use to enforce this coding rule?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's worth to try [flake8-import-graph](https://pypi.org/project/flake8-import-graph).

If you want some runtime checks, you can write a custom module importer. See [import-hooks](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#import-hooks) and an the [examples](https://realpython.com/python-import/).

Answer (score 1):

I would go with static analysis. That is, don't enforce this at runtime. You can use this along with tools for linting and testing your code.

My approach would be to adapt the scope example for import analysis from the LibCST project to enforce your import requirements.

https://libcst.readthedocs.io/en/latest/scope_tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you can't prevent someone from importing something that is found in his path, but you can modify the path to not include what you don't want to be accessible. I don't recommend it but it is feasible...

Comment: I don't see how this would be feasible by modifying sys.path, as it is shared globally by all packages.

Comment: Actually, you can. But you need to write a custom import  hook.